# reveal.js how to control volume of background video?

Tags: reveal.js

How can I control (change volume, play, pause) of a data-background-video in reveal.js when the slide is shown and the video already running?

I tried something like

```
<section data-state="myState" id="myID" data-background-video="small.ogv"></section>
```

and

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'myState', function() {
            document.getElementById('myID').dataset.backgroundVideo.volume=0.5;
} );
```

but it didn't work. Does anyone have a clue how to address and control the background video?